# How to fix Cannot convert value of type '()?' to expected argument type 'BeaconRealm?'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an API Manager, using the tutorial in [a link](https://medium.com/@pavlepesic/alamofire-api-manager-5b30c89477a1)

but i got error while implementing with my function

i'm using swift 4, and xcode, and alamofire.

```
func beaconUpdate(handler: @escaping (_ beacon: BeaconRealm?, _ error: AlertMessage?)->()){
         if let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token"){
            self.api.shared().call(type: EndpointItem.beaconData) { (beacon, message) in
                if var beacon = beacon{
                    handler(beacon,nil)
                } else{
                    handler(nil,message!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code edited with new answer
and
the error is showing

```
Cannot convert value of type '()?' to expected argument type 'BeaconRealm?'
```

Comment: The `beacon` parameter to the `handler` closure is of type `Beacon?` but the `handler` parameter inside the `call` completion block is of type `BeaconRealm`.

Comment: FYI -Once you fix that, get rid of that inner `if var` block and replace that whole bit with just `handler(beacon, message)`.

Comment: @rmaddy thankyou for answering, after i change the handler to BeaconRealm 
there is new error on the handler(beacon,nil)
Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'BeaconRealm?'

Comment: if your expected value type is BeaconRealm then you have to add BeaconRealm in handler instead of Beacon?

Comment: You should not be storing tokens in `UserDefaults`